# python :: MySQLdb connection fails, but pymysql doesn't. why?

Tags: python, mysql-python, pymysql

i have been working on this GUI app of mine, and i have noticed that pymysql is running a little bit slow, so i have made some research and i have found out that mysqlclient(MySQLdb) runs a lot faster.

so i went and fetched mysqlclient using `pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient`

but when i tried to use mysqlclient, My GUI started to break at the first line with MySQLdb in it.

i use QPushButtons to import-Export Data from/to my localhost using pandas and below you'll find the function linked to the 'ImportDatabaseButton':

```
def ImportDatabase(self):

    db = self.ImportDatabaseLineEdit.text()
    t  = self.ImportTableLineEdit.text()

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='mypass') # code breaks here.
    data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM %s.%s" %(db,t), con=conn)
    print(data)

    self.DatasetTableWidget.setRowCount(len(data.index))
    self.DatasetTableWidget.setColumnCount(len(data.columns))

    for indx in range(len(data.index)):
        for col in range(len(data.columns)):
            self.DatasetTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(data.columns)
            self.DatasetTableWidget.setItem(
                indx,
                col,
                QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data.iat[indx, col])))
```

before i used : `conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='mypass')` ,i had no problem with it, but with `MySQLdb`, it raises this error :

```
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\SQL_GUI>python c:/Users/pc/Desktop/SQL_GUI/testmw.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/pc/Desktop/SQL_GUI/testmw.py", line 964, in ImportDatabase
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='mypass')
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)
```

i have also tried `conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root','mypass')`, nothing changed, same error.

so Why pymysql works like a charm but MySQLdb doesn't ?

Comment: no i have not,. but i have just found this https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ and i am kind of lost now.

Comment: it didn't work, i tried **libmysqlclient** and **libmysqlclient-dev**

Comment: Official python 3.6.5 from python.org with Vscode IDE, MySQL 8.0.13

Comment: it does support it, type "MySQL supported python version" in google search and it'll give you all the supported version

Comment: i have installed a connector/python for python 3.6 8.0.13 and still doesn't work, so i think i'll stick with pymysql until i figure this mess out, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Version 8 is not compatible with flask-sqlalchemy.

You might need to downgrade for it to work.

Comment: i am not using Flask though, this GUI was built with PyQt5.

Comment: are you using any ORM?

Comment: i used sqlalchemy. but i removed it since i wanted to use mysqldb alone.

Comment: for this to work i need to install C library . so that's what i am going to do.